# Looking for software that allows me to look for a logo inside a group of images

Tags: gratis, ocr, search, image

I have between 60,000 and 100,000 images and 1.5% of them contain a specific logo. This logo is not always depicted in the same size or orientation. Is there a freeware program for Windows that would enable me to find/list only the images containing the logo?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should the software run on? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? What should it do with the "detected logo" (just say "found one" seems unlikely)? Please **[edit]** your question accordingly.